# No sound from Beep[]

Tags: sound

In Mathematica 12.1 under macOS 12.1, input

```
Beep[]
```

produces no audible sound.

On the other hand, input

```
Speak["Hello"]
```

produces the expected audible speech.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Mystery solved: the sound level from `Beep[]` is very soft, as I *can* hear it if I turn the iMac's sound level higher. The odd thing, though, is the disparity in sound level between that and the considerably louder output from `Speak`.

Comment: Here's a wrinkle: `Beep[]` plays from my laptop's speakers, while `Speak` plays from my monitor's (which is the output device selected under the volume menu).  This is also true if I generate the beep outside Mathematica.  In `System Preferences - Sound - Sound Effects`, it has Play sound effects through internal speakers, while `System Preferences - Sound - Output` has my monitor selected.  So maybe look there, since there is a separate volume slider for `Alert volume`.